# CIE Chromatic Diagram explanation

Tags: terminology, color, color-management

The MacAdam Ellipse is applied in the CIE Chromatic Diagram. I understand that humans distinguish some colors better then other colors (that's why the shape is eliptic / a horseshoe / inverted U-shape), and that the diagram is used to check wheter a specific color space is in or out of gamut.

The highest used y value is 0.84 (the top side of the ellipse ... it respresents 520 nanometers, green).
The lowest x value is 0.0 (the left bottom side of the ellipse ... it represents 380 nanometers, blue). 
And, on the right, at the coordinates: x 0.73, y 0.64, the red hue 680nm is displayed.

**What I don't understand:**

Why is this diagram non linear?

Why is the highest y value 0.84 and not just at y = 1.0?

How was the CIE Chromatic Diagram "derived"?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*Why is this diagram non linear?*

The CIE Chromatic diagram is a transformed 2D map of the CIE standard observer color matching functions. Because the human eye responds in a non-linear way to to different ranges of wavelengths, and the transformation does not compensate for that, the Yxy diagram isn't linear either.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Color_matching_functions
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/cie.html
http://dba.med.sc.edu/price/irf/Adobe_tg/models/ciexyz.html

*Why is the highest y value 0.84 and not just at y = 1.0?*

The y value is calculated according to this formula:
[image]

When measuring 520nm at the standard observer color match chart, one can see that

- X = ~0.08
- Y = ~0.69
- Z = ~0.08

Thus, 
y = (0.69/(0.08+0.69+0.08)) = ~0.81

[image]

*How was the CIE Chromatic Diagram "derived"?*

That's the hardest part: First the CIE RGB Model is transformed to the CIE XYZ Model, distorting the color space. Then a "slice" through the color space (X+Y+Z=1) is calculated, and finally that slice is projected to the base surface so that Z does not change it (Z is basically Y).

One rather good explanation is [Page 8 of "CIE Color Space" by Gernot Hoffmann](http://docs-hoffmann.de/ciexyz29082000.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram demonstrations page used for image in question](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CIEChromaticityDiagram/)

[Derivation of diagram from original data](http://www.cis.rit.edu/mcsl/research/broadbent/CIE1931_RGB.pdf) - a rare reference.

They say:

- Published accounts of the calculations used to derive the CIE 1931 RGB
  chromaticity co-ordinates and color matching functions are at best sketchy and on
  occasions data has not been published. This paper, and the accompanying worksheet
  1931CIE_RGB.xls, present in some detail the sequence of steps leading from the original
  experimental measurements of Wright and of Guild to the CIE 1931 RGB colorimetric
  system. It is not an easy story to unravel but the data presented here is probably a close
  representation of the actual calculations that were carried out by Guild just prior to the
  CIE meeting in Cambridge in 1931when the CIE 1931 standard observer was first
  specified. The further calculations transforming the RGB data into the XYZ of the CIE
  1931 standard observer have been describes by Fairman, Brill and Hemmendinger8

**Related:**

http://selfpace.uconn.edu/class/percep/CIE1931.pdf

Interactive:  http://www.biyee.net/color-science/cie-chromaticity-diagram/

Wikipedia  [Colour model](https://wiki2.org/en/Color_model)

Psychology Wiki - [CIE 1931 colour space](https://psychology.wikia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space)

Generating chromaticity diagrams [here](https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000229804-Q100330-Generating-chromaticity-diagrams)

Hyperphysics -  [Colour Perception](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html#c1%20)

Comment: The URL given is non-public, it seems: I got `You don't have permission to access /mcsl/research/broadbent/CIE1931_RGB.pdf on this server.`

Comment: The link `http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/Colors/Chromaticity.htm` is obsolete, too.

Comment: @U.Windl I can access the PDF without problem. The html link is dead (as you note). I've added 4 more references.